# Is there any way to create editable PDF files by using iTextSharp?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, pdf-generation, itext

We are using iTextSharp for creating PDF files using C#. But when I  am editing on the created PDF file by using some PDF editor,i am not able to make the editing perfectly.Because some edited texts are overlapped and some are unshown or hidden.So, i would like to choose some other approach to create editable PDF file using iTextSharp.

Is there any parameter(to make the PDF document editable) to add in order to create `editable PDF files` when building the PDF files by using iTextSharp?

Please guide me to get out of this issue?

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear what you're looking for.

PDF is NOT a format for editing text. Please read the intro of `Chapter 6` of "iText in Action". http://www.manning.com/lowagie2/samplechapter6.pdf .

However, there is a way to create interactive PDFs.

Browse to `section 6.3.5` and you'll learn about one type of interactive forms: forms based on AcroForm technology. In `section 6.3.5`, such a form is created using OpenOffice.

In `chapter 8`, you learn how to create AcroForm forms using iText. Of course: in such forms, all coordinates are fixed. A rectangle is defined, and content that doesn't fit into the rectangle can be scaled down (if the font = 0) or clipped. I guess that's what you're describing, but you're not being very clear.

Another type of form is based on the `XML Forms Architecture`. In this case, the PDF serves as a container for XML. You can create such forms using `Adobe LiveCycle Designer`. I don't know of any 'library' that can create such forms in an automated process. iTextSharp can inject XML in such forms to fill them; we also have a closed source product named `XFA Worker` that can flatten XFA forms.

Answer (score 1):

First your question isn't that clear.
Secondly, I assume you are trying to create PDFs just from C# code.

A way to vissualy improve this is to use `Open Office` to create the `PDF template`.
Then, after using the template you write in the editable fields you created in the template.
Here is some code to help you through:

```
public class DocumentDownload : PdfTemplateHandler 
{

    protected override string TemplatePath
    {
        get { return "~/App_Data/PdfTemplates/MyDocument_2011_v1.pdf"; }
    }

    protected override void LoadDataInternal()
    {

        documentType = Request["docType"] != null ? Request["docType"].ToString() : "";

        if (uid.Length < 1)
        {
            Response.Write("Invalid request!");
            Response.End();
        }
        // load data

        DownloadFileName = string.Format("MyDocument_{0}_{1}.pdf", 1234, DateTime.Now.ToBinary());
    }

    protected override void SetFieldsInternal(iTextSharp.text.pdf.AcroFields acroFields)
    {

        //iTextSharp.text.pdf.BaseFont unicode = iTextSharp.text.pdf.BaseFont.createFont(unicodeFontPath, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);            
        //var unicodeFont = iTextSharp.text.pdf.BaseFont.CreateFont(iTextSharp.text.FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN, iTextSharp.text.pdf.BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, iTextSharp.text.pdf.BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
        acroFields.SetField("txtrNumber", Number.ToString());

        acroFields.SetField("cbTaxi", "Yes");

    }
}


public abstract class PdfTemplateHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public virtual bool DownloadAsAttachment
    {
        get
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    protected virtual TimeSpan PdfTemplateCacheDuration
    {
        get
        {
            return TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
        }
    }

    protected virtual string PdfTemplateCacheKey
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Format("__PDF_Template[{0}]", TemplatePath);
        }
    }

    protected string DownloadFileName { get; set; }

    protected HttpContext Context { get; private set; }

    protected HttpResponse Response { get; private set; }

    protected HttpRequest Request { get; private set; }

    #region IHttpHandler Members

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {

        Context = context;
        Response = context.Response;
        Request = context.Request;

        try
        {
            LoadDataInternal();
        }
        catch (ThreadAbortException)
        {
            // no-op
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Logger.LogError(ex);
            Response.Write("Error!");
            Response.End();
        }

        Response.BufferOutput = true;
        Response.ClearHeaders();
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";

        if (DownloadAsAttachment)
        {
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" +
                (string.IsNullOrEmpty(DownloadFileName) ? context.Session.SessionID + ".pdf" : DownloadFileName));
        }

        PdfStamper pst = null;
        try
        {
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(GetTemplateBytes());
            pst = new PdfStamper(reader, Response.OutputStream);
            var acroFields = pst.AcroFields;

            pst.FormFlattening = true;
            pst.FreeTextFlattening = true;
            pst.SetFullCompression();

            SetFieldsInternal(acroFields);
            pst.Close();
        }
        finally
        {
            if (pst != null)
                pst.Close();
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Abstract Members for overriding and providing functionality

    protected abstract string TemplatePath { get; }

    protected abstract void LoadDataInternal();

    protected abstract void SetFieldsInternal(AcroFields acroFields);

    #endregion

    protected virtual byte[] GetTemplateBytes()
    {
        var data = Context.Cache[PdfTemplateCacheKey] as byte[];
        if (data == null)
        {
            data = File.ReadAllBytes(Context.Server.MapPath(TemplatePath));
            Context.Cache.Insert(PdfTemplateCacheKey, data,
                null, DateTime.Now.Add(PdfTemplateCacheDuration), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
        }
        return data;
    }

    protected static string unicode_iso8859(string src)
    {
        Encoding iso = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso8859-2");
        Encoding unicode = Encoding.UTF8;
        byte[] unicodeBytes = unicode.GetBytes(src);
        return iso.GetString(unicodeBytes);
    }
    protected static string RemoveDiacritics(string stIn)
    {
        string stFormD = stIn.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (int ich = 0; ich < stFormD.Length; ich++)
        {
            UnicodeCategory uc = CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(stFormD[ich]);
            if (uc != UnicodeCategory.NonSpacingMark)
            {
                sb.Append(stFormD[ich]);
            }
        }

        return (sb.ToString().Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormC));
    }

}
```

The PDF-template is **cacheable**. Keep that in mind when debugging.

Comment: @ Dragos Durlut:I am not creating any fields on pdf files.my pdf file have only text and i want to modify it by using pdf editor.Can i do this?

Comment: You should probably ask a question like this:
"How can I add Editable PDF fields to my PDF document using iTextSharp ?".

Comment: As an alternative, you may try using Aspose.Pdf for .NET as it provides great capabilities for adding as well as manipulating existing form fields in PDF document. Please check http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/pdfnet/Working+with+Forms